# Separating reserved identifiers in flex

Tags: bison, lex, flex-lexer

I have a language I am making a parser for which contains function calls. A few function names are reserved and I would like to handle them differently in my grammer. In EBNF it would look like

```
FunctionCall ::= FunctionName '(' ')'
SpecialFunctionCall :: SpecialName '(' ')'

FunctionName ::= VariableName - SpecialFunctionName

SpecialFunctionName ::= "special_function_a" | "special_function_b"
```

My problem is in translating the **exception** operator from **EBNF** to flex.

```
FunctionName    {Letter}{LetterOrDigit}
```

Is a super set of **SpecialFunctionName**, which is a hard-coded string

```
SpecialFunctionName   "special_function_a" | "special_function_b"
```

Hence I get a warning from bison saying that **SpecialFunction** will never be matched. Should I merge the tokens and compare the strings in the parser, or is there a recommended way to resolve this ambiguity in in flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way of dealing with this to have the lexical analyzer recognize the special names and return the correct token type (SpecialName) for the special names and a regular identifier token (apparently FunctionName) for the other tokens.

However, it normally requires an undue degree of prescience on the part of the lexical analyzer to say that a particular (non-reserved, non-special) word is a function name rather than a simple identifier (which could also be a simple variable - unless you've gone down the Perl route of using sigils to identify variables from functions).

Comment: "it normally requires an undue degree of prescience", could you elaborate?

Comment: @Akusete: in many grammars, there is no lexical difference between an identifier used for a variable and an identifier used for a function (Perl is an exception with its sigils).  So, for the lexical analyzer to determine that a particular name is a variable or function, it must have access to some non-lexical information (symbol table information).  If all variables and functions must be declared/defined before use, then the necessary information may be available - and you've avoided the need for prescience.  Languages like C are traditionally somewhat sloppy about this.  [...continued...]

Comment: @Akusete: the alternative is that the lexical analyzer looks ahead some number of tokens and determines from context that the name it is looking at must be a function name rather than an identifier - but you normally struggle to avoid imbuing that much knowledge of the grammar into the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to solve the ambiguity by having the lexer use the context of the previous token (In this language an operator must be preceded by a mutually exclusive set to variable names).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you put the `SpecialFunction` rule FIRST in the lexer file:

```
{SpecialFunctionName}    { return SpecialName; }
{FunctionName}           { return FunctionName; }
```

any identifer that matches both patterns will trigger the first rule and thus return `SpecialName` instead of `FunctionName`.